# How can i add more then one functions in a service or factory?

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

i must write a Service who has a lot of functions inside. This i must inject into a controller.
But, then i write a factory with 3 or more functions, angular found the first one, all others are undefined. - Why?

```
mySystem.factory('testFactory', function($http) {
return {
checkDates: function() {
    myData.VDate = myData.VDate.format('dd.MM.yyyy');
}

return {
    checkrequiered: function() {
    var check = true;
    if (myData.locId.lenght === 0) {
        check=false;
    }
    return check;
}

return {
    updateData: function() {
       '...'
    }
});
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you have three return statements, which means all but the first will be ignored. Return all the functions in a single object:

```
return {
    checkDates: function() {
        myData.VDate = myData.VDate.format('dd.MM.yyyy');
    },
    checkRequired: function() {
        return (myData.locId.length !== 0);
    },
    updateData: function() {
       '...'
    }
};
```

Comment: Next question:

How can i add the $scope variable in the functions?

Comment: @MarkusZuberhauser I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to use `$scope` inside a service. That would kinda defeat the purpose of using a service.